# IF AND Statement with multiple condition

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Need a formula that can return values MET & NOT MET in Excel 2010

The formula MET or NOT MET at the resolution time.

Below is the formula I tried but something is missing, because not sure how to write an IF statement to compare IF the Date Close is "**blank/open**" and IF the **SLA** is still "**within**" the **expected closure**..the value should be "MET" and also another  one how **IF** the expected closure date exceed the current date but still not closed..it should show NOT MET as the result.

[image]

```
IF(R13="","",IF(R13=0,"N/A",IF(AND(R13>0,U13=""),"NOT MET",IF(AND(R13="",U13=""),"",IF(V13<=R13,"MET",IF(V13>R13,"NOT MET"))))))
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is the purpose of your formula, because I tested your formula and it works, the only thing I changed is that cell="" was replaced with ISBLANK(cell).

Comment: 1) By Date Closed "blank/open" do you mean the cell is empty?  2)SLA within the expected closure: you haven't described what these columns mean so there's no obvious relationship between the two.  You need to operationally define that. 3) What's your difficulty with the last item (I assume you're familiar with TODAY())?  4) The current formula is working the way you want for what it includes?

Comment: sorry for the confusion 1) yes if the cell is **empty** 2) Expected closure is target date for the date closed..meaning the date closed should not exceed the Expected closure. 3) I am not sure how to write the if statement for the condition which compare the date closes vs the expected closure and the current formula not calculating the condition if the Date Close is empty but the expected closure already exceed the target date.

Comment: So if I comprehend what you are saying, you should have a target date somewhere (that is not the expected closure)? How can we find this (because we'll need it in the if statement).

Comment: @Michthan expected closure is the target date...

Comment: It isn't clear what your stumbling block is.  It looks like your existing formula already contains the kind of construction and comparisons you would use for the missing pieces.  Your formula begins with a test for empty.  You use AND() (which isn't limited to two conditions).  Date closed vs. expected closure: U13<=T13.  Date Close is empty but the expected closure already exceed the target date: you say expected closure **is** the target date.  If you mean it is already past the expected closure: AND(U13="",TODAY()>T13)

Comment: @fixer1234 You just mentioned what I was thinking too. Because in his comment he said "[...] the current formula not calculating the condition if the Date Close is empty but the expected closure already exceed the target date." It all is very confusing. Resh: The more clearly you state a problem, the more easily we can help you.

Comment: @fixer & Michthan...thank you for helping to understand the query. Let me try to explain again..basically I need the column  (Resolution Time) to give a value Met or Not Met based on the criteria as 1) If the Date Close <= Expected Closure = Met, 2) if the Date Close > Expected Closure = Not Met...for this 2 condition I already have the working formula which is '=IF(U13="","",IF(U13="N/A","N/A",IF(V13<=R13,"MET",IF(V13>R13,"NOT MET"))))'

Comment: how about when the Date Close is still **blank** and the current date already exceed the Expected Closure(Date) and also if the Date Close is **blank** but the current date does not exceed the Expected Closure(Date)...

Comment: A suggestion that will help organize the rules.  Create a "truth table".  Have a column for each variable that can affect the outcome via a rule plus a column for the result (met, not met, etc.).  Then each row lists one rule by showing, in the column for each relevant variable, the condition (the test you would evaluate for that item in an IF), and then the end result for that rule (the "true").  Everything you would connect with AND is part of the rule.  Anything that would be OR is split; each alternative becomes part of a separate rule (single condition for any variable per rule). (cont'd)

Comment: The table entries don't contain "IF", just the test.  So if one column is Date Closed, the cell entry might be U13="" in one case and U13<=T13 in another.  This is similar to what you've described in comments but a little more structured, so easier to visualize how the rules relate.  Include in that table every rule, and add it to the question.  You can create it in Excel and then use a site like http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables to create a text version you can paste in the question (paste, then select the whole table, and click on the code block icon to preserve the formatting).

Comment: Dear @fixer1234 it would be helpful if you can show me one sample.

Comment: I created something to get you started and populated it with what I could cobble together from the question and comments: http://www.filedropper.com/truthtable (no need to sign up, just click download).  You can clean it up and flesh it out.  Include every rule that applies to your problem.  Then you can add a screen grab to the question.

Comment: @fixer1234 i am still a bit lost..sorry once done the truth table as per the sample how to link the truth table to the working sheet..what would be the formula

Comment: Add that to your question.  Part of the reason you haven't gotten a solution yet is that the requirements are hard to follow, and spread over the question and comments.  The table will organize the whole problem clearly and in one place, and people will be able to help with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

if met and non-met are opposites (meaning both can not be true or false at the same time) then formula should be of the form if(Test(Met),"Met","Not Met") For testing(Met) date_close < 1+date_expected  then put this in an iferror wrapper

- iferror(v13<1+u13,"false")

This results into the full form of

- =if(iferror(v13<1+u13,"false","Met","Not Met")

The +1 is so if June 13 is the expected date, and it is closed on June 13 that it is considered MET. Otherwise since it is a Date+Time field the hours might could mess things up where sometimes it is met, and then for others it is not met.